# Hudson cyclic dependencies

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Is there a method of checking for cyclic dependencies between jobs in Hudson? It is simple to observe if A->B->A but if A->B->C->D->A then its almost impossible manually. Is there a plugin to do this? I think it is key functionality because such a loop between build triggers can slowly kill a server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Downstream build view](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Downstream+buildview+plugin) plugin. It's not a cycle detector, but it might help.

I understand the concern, but do you really have a situation where the builds do not fall into a heirarchy such that it makes no sense for build D to trigger build A?

Comment: yes I really do have that situation. I am working with a project of 2 million LOC, no testing and a dependency tree to make you weep.

Answer (score 1):

Hudson has cycle detection in the regular downstream trigger setup.  If you are using mechanisms outside of the downstream trigger, it's not clear how to detect the cycle.

Comment: Nice! I did not know that. Do you have a reference? I couldn't find this fact on the wiki.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug (Hudson 1.348), but I created a trivial test case (A is configured to build B, B is configured to build A) and when I kicked it off it started the *really* "continuous" build, ha ha :)

Comment: yes I had the same issue. My worry however is with more complicated loops that are difficult to see.